# Jquery click event not working using class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jquery 3.3.1, when I try to display some data using onclick event on class, it cannot trigger the code, but when I used `id` it does.

Below are my code.

> Not working

```
$(document).on('click', '.toggle', function () {
  alert('yes');
});
```

> Working

```
$(document).on('click', '#toggle', function () {
  alert('yes');
});
```

Comment: Can you include the corresponding HTML please?

Comment: ok, will edit the question

Comment: Sorry Guys, I rechecked once and found that I have two class attributes...xdxd
Thanks for your attentions, now everything is working fine Thanks for your time

Comment: make sure your target element has the assigned class **toggle**

Answer (score 2):

You should find that your script provided that your HTML includes elements matching the `#toggle` and/or `.toggle` selectors.

Note that `.toggle` is a [class selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors), meaning that you'll need to have an element with a class attribute along the lines of `class="toggle"` in your HTML for your first script snippet to work:

```
<button class="toggle">With Class</button>
```

Please see the snippet below for a working example of both cases:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.toggle', function () {
  alert('works with class');
});

$(document).on('click', '#toggle', function () {
  alert('works with id');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- id attribute requires "#toggle" selector -->
<button id="toggle">With ID</button>

<!-- class attribute required ".toggle" selector -->
<button class="toggle">With Class</button>
```

If you are still encountering issues, ensure that there are no other script errors reported by the browser and that jQuery (and other dependencies) have successfully loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Bind an event handler to the "click" JavaScript event, or trigger that event on an element.

```
<!-- id attribute  -->
<button id="btnID"> BUTTON BY ID</button>

<!-- class attribute  -->
<button class="btnCLASS">BUTTON BY CLASS</button>


$(document).ready(function() {


     $("#btnID").click(function(event){ 

        });


     $(".btnCLASS").click(function(event){ 

     });

} );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also be more specific to click so in case class or id is added dynamically it may not cause any issue later.

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.toggle', function () {
  alert('works with class');
});

$(document).on('click', 'a#toggle', function () {
  alert('works with id');
});
```

Only Anchor tags having class or id as toggle will get response in case if you have multiple toggle class.
Hope it helps.Thanks